# How can I enclose content between two divs in a div

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have been through:

1. [Wrap plain text in paragraph Jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64858944/wrap-plain-text-in-paragraph-jquery)
2. [Wrap text within element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13652140/wrap-text-within-element)
3. [Wrap element between two elements in JavaScript/jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15347032/wrap-element-between-two-elements-in-javascript-jquery)
4. [jQuery wrapAll contents including text between two tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31552301/jquery-wrapall-contents-including-text-between-two-tags)
5. [Get the text after span element using jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6925088/get-the-text-after-span-element-using-jquery)
   none of those provide a solution for what I am trying to do.  I think adding the div may be part of the reason.

How can I enclose the content between div_1 and div_2 in a div_3

```
<div id="div_1"></div>
<strong>stuff here that always begins with same string but does not end that way</strong>
some unknown text here
<div id="div_2"></div>
```

The real issue is that it seems you cannot insert the beginning of a div without the end of div showing up automatically.

For example, if I do something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#div_1').after('<div id="div_3">');
$('#div_2').before('</div>');
});
```

div_3 gets inserted after div_1 but with a closing tag i.e.

```
<div id="div_1"></div>
<div id="div_3"></div>
    <strong>stuff here that always begins with same string but does not end that way</strong>
    some text here with no consistent string
    <div id="div_2"></div>
```

Comment: The problem is that you're thinking in HTML and not in DOM.

Comment: Please take the [tour]. Answers do not belong in your question.

Comment: Protip: Just about anything you can wish to do with jQuery has been covered on SO already. Also, a regular review of the [methods available to you](https://api.jquery.com/) will give good hints about how to tackle a particular challenge.

Comment: NONE of the "This question already has answers here" pertain to my situation.  I had been through all of them already

Answer (score 1):

You can enclose the content between div_1 and div_2 inside a new div element using the following jQuery code:

```
$('#div_1').nextUntil('#div_2').wrapAll('<div id="dev_3"></div>');
```

Comment: Sweet, thanks.  Now I just discovered the 'some unknown text here' has a variable amount of <br> tags and all those get bunched up after the <strong> content. So `code`<div id="div_1"></div>
<strong>stuff here that always begins with same string but does not end that way</strong>
some text here<br>more stuff<br>even more stuff
<div id="div_2"></div>`code` becomes 'code'<div id="dev_3"><strong>stuff here that always begins with same string but does not end that way</strong><br><br></div>`code`