# How can I enclose content between two divs into a div via inserting a div, put the content in the third div and remove the original content?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, insert

I have been through:

1. [Wrap plain text in paragraph Jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64858944/wrap-plain-text-in-paragraph-jquery)
2. [Wrap text within element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13652140/wrap-text-within-element)
3. [Wrap element between two elements in JavaScript/jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15347032/wrap-element-between-two-elements-in-javascript-jquery)
4. [jQuery wrapAll contents including text between two tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31552301/jquery-wrapall-contents-including-text-between-two-tags)
5. [Get the text after span element using jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6925088/get-the-text-after-span-element-using-jquery)

none of those provide a solution for what I am trying to do.  I think adding the div may be part of the reason.

How can I enclose the content between div_1 and div_2 in a div_3

```
<div id="div_1"></div>
<strong>stuff here that always begins with same string but does not end that way</strong>
some unknown text here<br>more text<br>even more text
<div id="div_2"></div>
```

The real issue is that it seems you cannot insert the beginning of a div without the end of div showing up automatically.

For example, if I do something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#div_1').after('<div id="div_3">');
$('#div_2').before('</div>');
});
```

div_3 gets inserted after div_1 but with a closing tag i.e.

```
<div id="div_1"></div>
<div id="div_3"></div>
    <strong>stuff here that always begins with same string but does not end that way</strong>
    some unknown text here
    <div id="div_2"></div>
```

I can get it to work but it cuts out after first `<br>` using:

```
document.getElementById("div_1").parentNode.insertBefore(document.createElement("div"), document.getElementById("div_2")).id = "div_3";
var text_1 = document.getElementById("div_1").nextElementSibling.outerHTML + document.getElementById("div_1").nextElementSibling.nextSibling.nodeValue;
document.getElementById("div_3").innerHTML = text_1 + document.getElementById("div_1").nextSibling.innerHTML;

// Get the elements
let div1 = document.getElementById("div_1");
let div3 = document.getElementById("div_3");

// Get the content between the two divs
let content = div1.nextSibling;

// Remove the content
while (content != div3) {
  content.remove();
  content = div1.nextSibling;
}
```

Also, [Shahbaz Naeem](https://stackoverflow.com/users/21325835/shahbaz-naeem), proposed this solution before my first question was (incorrectly) tagged a duplicate

```
$('#div_1').nextUntil('#div_2').wrapAll('<div id="dev_3"></div>');
```

But same thing, it cuts out after first `<br>`

Comment: The problem is that you're *[still](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75695814/how-can-i-enclose-content-between-two-divs-in-a-div#comment133539921_75695814)* thinking in HTML and not in DOM.

Comment: Can you include an example of "before" HTML in the question itself, where `.wrapAll` doesn't work - it's too hard to see from [your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75695899/2181514) on your previous question why it doesn't work.

Comment: Honestly, not sure what you mean by thinking in HTML instead of DOM but given "some unknown text here<br>more text<br>even more text" has no tags, isn't it outside the realm of DOM?  Will try the .wrapAll, thanks

Comment: Here's an example for you where it's not "correctly" applying the div3: https://jsfiddle.net/085ymbt9/

Comment: To clarify: DOM are objects.    You have a `div` and it has content.  It doesn't have a start-end tag, HTML has start-end tags.  So you can't insert a start-tag in one place and an end-tag elsewhere as these concepts don't exist in the DOM.  When you attempt to insert only the start-tag, jquery goes "ah, you can't have a start tag without an end tag, so they must mean `<div></div>`" and generates an object `div` and inserts the object, not individual HTML markup.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [freedomm-m](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2181514/freedomn-m)'s tip of `.wrapAll` I ended up with this

```
  let div1 = document.getElementById('div_1');
  let div2 = document.getElementById('div_2');
  let div3 = document.createElement('div');
  div3.setAttribute('id','div_3');
  div2.parentNode.insertBefore(div3, div2);
  let content = div1.nextSibling;
  let contentElements = [];
  while(content && content !== div2) {
    contentElements.push(content);
    content = content.nextSibling;
  }
  $(contentElements).wrapAll(div3);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/akmiecik/hzetk3pw/72/

Answer (score 0):

First, let's have a proof-of-concept

```js
setTimeout(function() {
    let html1 = document.getElementById("div_1").outerHTML;
    let html2 = document.getElementById("div_2").outerHTML;
    let bodyHTML = document.body.innerHTML;
    let content = bodyHTML.substring(bodyHTML.indexOf(html1) + html1.length, bodyHTML.indexOf(html2));
    document.body.innerHTML = bodyHTML.substring(0, bodyHTML.indexOf(content)) + `<div id="div_3">${content}</div>` + bodyHTML.substring(bodyHTML.indexOf(html2));
}, 1500)
```

```css
div {
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 100px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

#div_1 {
    background-color: red;
}

#div_2 {
    background-color: green;
}

#div_3 {
    background-color: #4596ff;
}
```

```html
<div id="div_1"></div>
<strong>stuff here that always begins with same string but does not end that way</strong>
some unknown text here
<div id="div_2"></div>
```

Explanation: the `innerHTML` is the inner HTML of the element. The `outerHTML` is the outer HTML of the element. These can be treated as strings and we can override them with strings, the result ending up being an HTML.